# Magento 2 UPS API estimated delivery date

Tags: magento2, shipping, ups

How can I add estimate delivery date for UPS shipping method. I searching over google but not luck and I try to following link for magento 1 [UPS estimate delivery date](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147208/ups-api-estimated-delivery-date) but not work. I also check ups inTransit api but not convert in magento 2 any one know how can I achieve this.

Comment: Looks like the link you provided is for Magento 1 but your question has a magento2 tag

Comment: Yes i need it in magento 2 not in 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

step1:- Override carrier.php file in local module 
Vendor\module-ups\Model\Carrier.php

Find function setRequest() and add DestCity.

```
public function setRequest(RateRequest $request)
{
        $rowRequest->setDestCity($request->getDestCity());
        $this->_rawRequest = $rowRequest;
        return $this;
}
```

step2:- Find function _getXmlQuotes().

```
protected function _getXmlQuotes()
    {
        $url = $this->getConfigData('gateway_xml_url');

        $this->setXMLAccessRequest();
        $xmlRequest = $this->_xmlAccessRequest;
        $debugData['accessRequest'] = $this->filterDebugData($xmlRequest);

        $rowRequest = $this->_rawRequest;
        if (self::USA_COUNTRY_ID == $rowRequest->getDestCountry()) {
            $destPostal = substr($rowRequest->getDestPostal(), 0, 5);
        } else {
            $destPostal = $rowRequest->getDestPostal();
        }
        $params = [
            'accept_UPS_license_agreement' => 'yes',
            '10_action' => $rowRequest->getAction(),
            '13_product' => $rowRequest->getProduct(),
            '14_origCountry' => $rowRequest->getOrigCountry(),
            '15_origPostal' => $rowRequest->getOrigPostal(),
            'origCity' => $rowRequest->getOrigCity(),
            'origRegionCode' => $rowRequest->getOrigRegionCode(),
            '19_destPostal' => $destPostal,
            '22_destCountry' => $rowRequest->getDestCountry(),
            'destRegionCode' => $rowRequest->getDestRegionCode(),
            '23_weight' => $rowRequest->getWeight(),
            '47_rate_chart' => $rowRequest->getPickup(),
            '48_container' => $rowRequest->getContainer(),
            '49_residential' => $rowRequest->getDestType(),
        ];
        // start change action name Shop to Shoptimeintransit
        if ($params['10_action'] == '4') {
            $params['10_action'] = 'Shoptimeintransit';
            $serviceCode = null;
        } else {
            $params['10_action'] = 'Rate';
            $serviceCode = $rowRequest->getProduct() ? $rowRequest->getProduct() : '';
        }
        // end
        $serviceDescription = $serviceCode ? $this->getShipmentByCode($serviceCode) : '';

        $xmlParams = <<<XMLRequest
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RatingServiceSelectionRequest xml:lang="en-US">
  <Request>
    <TransactionReference>
      <CustomerContext>Rating and Service</CustomerContext>
      <XpciVersion>1.0</XpciVersion>
    </TransactionReference>
    <RequestAction>Rate</RequestAction>
    <RequestOption>{$params['10_action']}</RequestOption>
  </Request>
  <PickupType>
          <Code>{$params['47_rate_chart']['code']}</Code>
          <Description>{$params['47_rate_chart']['label']}</Description>
  </PickupType>

  <Shipment>
XMLRequest;

        if ($serviceCode !== null) {
            $xmlParams .= "<Service>" .
                "<Code>{$serviceCode}</Code>" .
                "<Description>{$serviceDescription}</Description>" .
                "</Service>";
        }

        $xmlParams .= <<<XMLRequest
      <Shipper>
XMLRequest;

        if ($this->getConfigFlag('negotiated_active') && ($shipper = $this->getConfigData('shipper_number'))) {
            $xmlParams .= "<ShipperNumber>{$shipper}</ShipperNumber>";
        }

        if ($rowRequest->getIsReturn()) {
            $shipperCity = '';
            $shipperPostalCode = $params['19_destPostal'];
            $shipperCountryCode = $params['22_destCountry'];
            $shipperStateProvince = $params['destRegionCode'];
        } else {
            $shipperCity = $params['origCity'];
            $shipperPostalCode = $params['15_origPostal'];
            $shipperCountryCode = $params['14_origCountry'];
            $shipperStateProvince = $params['origRegionCode'];
        }

        $xmlParams .= <<<XMLRequest
      <Address>
          <City>{$shipperCity}</City>
          <PostalCode>{$shipperPostalCode}</PostalCode>
          <CountryCode>{$shipperCountryCode}</CountryCode>
          <StateProvinceCode>{$shipperStateProvince}</StateProvinceCode>
      </Address>
    </Shipper>
    <ShipTo>
      XMLRequest;

/* ------- Start XML Mod to add city ---------*/
$xmlRequest .= <<< XMLRequest
            <City>{$rowRequest->getDestCity()}</City>
XMLRequest;
/* ---------------- End of XML Mod --------------------*/

$xmlRequest .= <<< XMLRequest
          /* ------- XML Mod For Time In Transit Params ---------*/         

          <PostalCode>{$params['19_destPostal']}</PostalCode>
          <CountryCode>{$params['22_destCountry']}</CountryCode>
          <ResidentialAddress>{$params['49_residential']}</ResidentialAddress>
          <StateProvinceCode>{$params['destRegionCode']}</StateProvinceCode>
XMLRequest;

        if ($params['49_residential'] === '01') {
            $xmlParams .= "<ResidentialAddressIndicator>{$params['49_residential']}</ResidentialAddressIndicator>";
        }

        $xmlParams .= <<<XMLRequest
      </Address>
    </ShipTo>


    <ShipFrom>
      <Address>
          <PostalCode>{$params['15_origPostal']}</PostalCode>
          <CountryCode>{$params['14_origCountry']}</CountryCode>
          <StateProvinceCode>{$params['origRegionCode']}</StateProvinceCode>
      </Address>
    </ShipFrom>

    <Package>
      <PackagingType><Code>{$params['48_container']}</Code></PackagingType>
      <PackageWeight>
         <UnitOfMeasurement><Code>{$rowRequest->getUnitMeasure()}</Code></UnitOfMeasurement>
        <Weight>{$params['23_weight']}</Weight>
      </PackageWeight>
    </Package>
        /* ------- XML Mod Start for deliverytime ---------*/
        <DeliveryTimeInformation>
        <PackageBillType>03</PackageBillType>
    </DeliveryTimeInformation>
        /* ---------------- End of XML Mod --------------------*/
XMLRequest;

        if ($this->getConfigFlag('negotiated_active')) {
            $xmlParams .= "<RateInformation><NegotiatedRatesIndicator/></RateInformation>";
        }

/* ---------------- End of XML Mod --------------------*/
        $xmlParams .= <<<XMLRequest
  </Shipment>
</RatingServiceSelectionRequest>
XMLRequest;

        $xmlRequest .= $xmlParams;

        $xmlResponse = $this->_getCachedQuotes($xmlRequest);
        if ($xmlResponse === null) {
            $debugData['request'] = $xmlParams;
            try {
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, (bool)$this->getConfigFlag('mode_xml'));
                $xmlResponse = curl_exec($ch);
                if ($xmlResponse !== false) {
                    $debugData['result'] = $xmlResponse;
                    $this->_setCachedQuotes($xmlRequest, $xmlResponse);
                } else {
                    $debugData['result'] = ['error' => curl_error($ch)];
                }
                curl_close($ch);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $debugData['result'] = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'code' => $e->getCode()];
                $xmlResponse = '';
            }

            $this->_debug($debugData);
        }

        return $this->_parseXmlResponse($xmlResponse);
    }
```

step3:- Find Function _parseXmlResponse()

```
protected function _parseXmlResponse($xmlResponse)
    {
        $costArr = [];
        $priceArr = [];
        if (strlen(trim($xmlResponse)) > 0) {
            $xml = new \Magento\Framework\Simplexml\Config();
            $xml->loadString($xmlResponse);
            $arr = $xml->getXpath("//RatingServiceSelectionResponse/Response/ResponseStatusCode/text()");
            $success = (int)$arr[0];
            if ($success === 1) {
                $arr = $xml->getXpath("//RatingServiceSelectionResponse/RatedShipment");
                $allowedMethods = explode(",", $this->getConfigData('allowed_methods'));

                // Negotiated rates
                $negotiatedArr = $xml->getXpath("//RatingServiceSelectionResponse/RatedShipment/NegotiatedRates");
                $negotiatedActive = $this->getConfigFlag(
                        'negotiated_active'
                    ) && $this->getConfigData(
                        'shipper_number'
                    ) && !empty($negotiatedArr);

                $allowedCurrencies = $this->_currencyFactory->create()->getConfigAllowCurrencies();
                foreach ($arr as $shipElement) {
                    $code = (string)$shipElement->Service->Code;
                    if (in_array($code, $allowedMethods)) {
                        if ($negotiatedActive) {
                            $cost = $shipElement->NegotiatedRates->NetSummaryCharges->GrandTotal->MonetaryValue;
                        } else {
                            $cost = $shipElement->TotalCharges->MonetaryValue;
                        }
                        /* ------------ Time In Transit Mod ------------*/

                        $daysInTransit = $shipElement->TimeInTransit->ServiceSummary->EstimatedArrival->TotalTransitDays;
                        //print_r($daysInTransit);die;
                        $etaDate = $shipElement->TimeInTransit->ServiceSummary->EstimatedArrival->Arrival->Date;
                        $etaTime = $shipElement->TimeInTransit->ServiceSummary->EstimatedArrival->Arrival->Time;
                        $eta = new \DateTime();
                        $eta->setDate(substr($etaDate, 0, 4), substr($etaDate, 4, 2), substr($etaDate, 6, 2));
                        $eta->setTime(substr($etaTime, 0, 2), substr($etaTime, 4, 2), substr($etaTime, 4, 2));

                        /* ----------- End Time In Transit Mod ---------*/
                        //convert price with Origin country currency code to base currency code
                        $successConversion = true;
                        $responseCurrencyCode = $this->mapCurrencyCode(
                            (string)$shipElement->TotalCharges->CurrencyCode
                        );
                        if ($responseCurrencyCode) {
                            if (in_array($responseCurrencyCode, $allowedCurrencies)) {
                                $cost = (double)$cost * $this->_getBaseCurrencyRate($responseCurrencyCode);
                            } else {
                                $errorTitle = __(
                                    'We can\'t convert a rate from "%1-%2".',
                                    $responseCurrencyCode,
                                    $this->_request->getPackageCurrency()->getCode()
                                );
                                $error = $this->_rateErrorFactory->create();
                                $error->setCarrier('ups');
                                $error->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
                                $error->setErrorMessage($errorTitle);
                                $successConversion = false;
                            }
                        }

                        if ($successConversion) {
                            $costArr[$code] = $cost;
                            $priceArr[$code] = $this->getMethodPrice(floatval($cost), $code);
                             /* ------------ Time In Transit Mod ------------*/

                            $timeInTransitArr[$code] = $daysInTransit;
                            $etaArr[$code] = $eta;

                            /* ----------- End Time In Transit Mod ---------*/  
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $arr = $xml->getXpath("//RatingServiceSelectionResponse/Response/Error/ErrorDescription/text()");
                $errorTitle = (string)$arr[0][0];
                $error = $this->_rateErrorFactory->create();
                $error->setCarrier('ups');
                $error->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
                $error->setErrorMessage($this->getConfigData('specificerrmsg'));
            }
        }

        $result = $this->_rateFactory->create();

        if (empty($priceArr)) {
            $error = $this->_rateErrorFactory->create();
            $error->setCarrier('ups');
            $error->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
            if (!isset($errorTitle)) {
                $errorTitle = __('Cannot retrieve shipping rates');
            }
           $error->setErrorMessage($this->getConfigData('specificerrmsg'));

            /* ------------ Time In Transit Mod ------------*/

            $error->setErrorMessage($errorTitle);

             /* ----------- End Time In Transit Mod ---------*/

            $result->append($error);
        } else {
            foreach ($priceArr as $method => $price) {
                $rate = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
                $rate->setCarrier('ups');
                $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
                $rate->setMethod($method);
                $methodArr = $this->getShipmentByCode($method);
                /* ------------ Time In Transit Mod ------------*/

                //$transitDays = intval($timeInTransitArr[$method]);
                $rate->setMethodTitle($methodArr . ' (ETA: ' . $etaArr[$method]->format('d-m-Y H:i'). ')');

                /* ----------- End Time In Transit Mod ---------*/
               // $rate->setMethodTitle($methodArr);
                $rate->setCost($costArr[$method]);
                $rate->setPrice($price);
                $result->append($rate);
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: I get a blank page with:"Estimate Shipping and Tax" when I edit this page. Is there any additional step or maybe I didn't insert the dest city at the right place. Any imput would be appreciated

Comment: Working fine, also used below line of code also.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace

```
$daysInTransit = $shipElement->TimeInTransit->ServiceSummary->EstimatedArrival->TotalTransitDays;
```

with

```
 $daysInTransit = (string)$shipElement->TimeInTransit->ServiceSummary->EstimatedArrival->BusinessDaysInTransit;
```

Comment: With above code, i was facing this error also and this code help me.

Comment: Then you need to print $shipElement and check the data.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Magento 2.4. I modified `Carier.php` file of UPS Module to fetch  Estimate delivery Date and time from UPS API. I used above code but it was throwing error "Invalid weight" so I used additional parameter in `<shipment>` tag
Below code is required because when you pass `$params['10_action'] = 'Shoptimeintransit';` ,so you need to add new element `ShipmentTotalWeight` in `shipment` container

```
 <Shipment>
    ........
    <ShipmentTotalWeight>
        <UnitOfMeasurement>
            <Code>{$rowRequest->getUnitMeasure()}</Code>
        </UnitOfMeasurement>
        <Weight>{$params['23_weight']}</Weight>
    </ShipmentTotalWeight>
    .......
 </Shipment>
```