# MAGENTO - want to get delievery date from UPS

Tags: magento-1.9, api, ups

How can I get the delivery date from the UPS?

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Check this out. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147208/ups-api-estimated-delivery-date and this one
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221363/magento-2-ups-api-estimated-delivery-date

Comment: Hi John, I have checked those links already, didn't get this much. But I was looking at core and I have found a method in app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php => getTracking($trackings) where it gives delivery date. So dose any one have ideas how to call and get information of delivery date?